# Two JSFiddles with the exact same code but one works and the other doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api

The following SJFiddle works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/JMPerez/62wafrm7/

I created a second SJFiddle to test it and copied everything (HTML/CSS/JS) exactly the same from the first one. I also included the same resources but it doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/kennethcode/dz1tubf6/

HTML is the same for both

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Displaying User Data</h1>
    <p>Log in with your Spotify account and this demo will display information about you fetched using the Spotify Web API</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-login">Login</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>
<script id="result-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <dl>
      <img src="{{images.0.url}}">
      <dt>User Name</dt>
      <dd>{{id}}</dd>
      <dt>Display Name</dt>
      <dd>{{display_name}}</dd>
      <dt>Country</dt>
      <dd>{{country}}</dd>
      <dt>Followers</dt>
      <dd>{{followers.total}}</dd>
      <dt>Profile</dt>
      <dd><a href="{{external_urls.spotify}}" target="_blank">{{external_urls.spotify}}</a></dd>
      <dt>Email</dt>
      <dd>{{email}}</dd>
      <dt>Product</dt>
      <dd>{{product}}</dd>
    </dl>
</script>
```

JavaScript is the same for both

```
(function() {

    function login(callback) {
        var CLIENT_ID = '6b284830006843e7ae7b170725715aed';
        var REDIRECT_URI = 'http://jmperezperez.com/spotify-oauth-jsfiddle-proxy/';
        function getLoginURL(scopes) {
            return 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=' + CLIENT_ID +
              '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(REDIRECT_URI) +
              '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scopes.join(' ')) +
              '&response_type=token';
        }

        var url = getLoginURL([
            'user-read-email'
        ]);

        var width = 450,
            height = 730,
            left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2),
            top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);

        window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
            var hash = JSON.parse(event.data);
            if (hash.type == 'access_token') {
                callback(hash.access_token);
            }
        }, false);

        var w = window.open(url,
                            'Spotify',
                            'menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no, width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left
                           );

    }

    function getUserData(accessToken) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
            headers: {
               'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
            }
        });
    }

    var templateSource = document.getElementById('result-template').innerHTML,
        template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource),
        resultsPlaceholder = document.getElementById('result'),
        loginButton = document.getElementById('btn-login');

    loginButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        login(function(accessToken) {
            getUserData(accessToken)
                .then(function(response) {
                    loginButton.style.display = 'none';
                    resultsPlaceholder.innerHTML = template(response);
                });
            });
    });

})();
```

CSS is the same for both

```
.container {
    margin: 1em;
}

img {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Any clues why this might be happening? Thanks

Comment: Please add a [mcve] **in the question itself** and not only a link to an external resource that might not be available/reachable for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Check the “Resources” section in the sidebar. The first one has these 3 additional resources:

- cached.css
- handlebars.min.js
- jquery-1.10.1.min.js

Comment: Thanks Ted, I added the same 3 resources but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just add manually the required scripts in **the top of html section**:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/static/css/cached.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's not possible I just forked your fiddle and added the scripts it works. https://jsfiddle.net/fdgdfgdd/o1sn3L4q/2/

Comment: Sorry Melchia, I did what you suggested but it doesn't work for me. Perhaps you only saw the Spotify pop-up log-in window opening? But; Did you actually test it by logging-in to see if your data loads? That's where the problem is, after logging-in the user's data is supposed to load like in the first JSFiddle but it doesn't work on the second one.

Comment: Of course I'm not going to sign in using untrusted oidc (that's why I used my own). The clientID in the application must have a few allowed urls ( one of them must be the url of the original fiddler). If you want your own go generate it in https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/app-settings/

Comment: thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. The clientID only allows the url in the REDIRECT_URI. This is the url of a file that contains a script which specifies the host with exact protocol and domain for the script to work. The second Fiddle's address uses HTTPS while the first Fiddle has HTTP, that's why it wasn't working. After figuring out how it worked I registered my own as you suggested, allowing my own urls. I'm new to Web API's so thanks for your help.